# Need to perform self destruct contract

Tags: blockchain, ether, dapps, selfdestruct, code

I have been involved in a scam and need to get my funds transfered to another wallet in my name.  I assume there is a contract preventing send capability, so I need someone who knows how to perform a self destruct on the contract so the send request carries through.  Please help.....anyone?

Comment: Generally you can't add logic to a deployed smart contract. In any case, post its code and we can try to help.